# Equation transposition

Tags: fractions

I am struggling to see how an equation has been transposed. It is probably pretty easy, so apologies in advance.

If possible; please show the transposition stages:

$V_{out} = V1 . \frac{R2}{R1 + R2} (\frac{R3 + R4}{R3}) - V2 . \frac {R4} {R3}$

this is then transposed to.....

$V_{out} = (V1 - V2) \frac {R4} {R3}$

Comment: Do you know any relations between the different $R_i$?

Comment: Hi. This equation comes from an engineering textbook to describe the operation of a component. The textbook states that R1 can be equivalent to R3 and that R2 can be equivalent to R4.

Answer (score 0):

Without further conditions relating $R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4$ to one another, these two equations are not equivalent.

**EDIT**: You say that $R_1 = R_3$ and $R_2 = R_4$.  In that case,

\begin{align*}
V_1 &\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\right) \left(\frac{R_3 + R_4}{R_3}\right) - V_2 . \frac {R_4} {R_3} \\[3mm]
&= V_1 \left(\frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4}\right) \left(\frac{R_3 + R_4}{R_3}\right) - V_2  \frac {R_4} {R_3} \\[3mm]
&= V1 \frac{R_4}{R_3} - V2  \frac {R_4} {R_3} = (V1 - V2) \frac{R_4}{R_3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi. This equation comes from an engineering textbook to describe the operation of a component. The textbook states that R1 can be equivalent to R3 and that R2 can be equivalent to R4.

Comment: Then change all the R1's to R3 and all the R2's to R4's in the equation.

Comment: If you changed the R1s and R2s to R3s and R4s, why are there still R1s and R2s there?

Comment: Hi Daniel; thanks for the advice. I did try that, but I still could not get to the answer. First I tried to multiply out the brackets in the first term:                  R2 / R1 + R2 (R3 + R4 / R3)                                                                               by multiplying the numerators and the denominators to get                          R2R3 + R2R4 on the numerator, and R1R3 + R2R3 on the denominator. Next, I collected both V terms together to get 'V1 - V2'.                                        I subtracted R2R3 + R2R4 \ R1R3 + R2R3 and R4 \ R3, but still could not get it

Comment: Edited answer to respond.